# Convergence of an infinite sum where each term converges to zero

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Lets say we have a countably infinite sum $\sum_{i=1}^\infty |x^{(n)}_i|$ and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}|x_i^{(n)}| = 0$.

Does this imply that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^\infty |x^{(n)}_i| = 0$.

What is wrong with this line of reasoning?

- For each $x_i^{(n)}$, pick an $N_i$ such that for $n > N_i$,  $|x_i^{(n)}| < \frac{\epsilon}{2^i}$ for $\epsilon > 0$
- Let $N = \sup_i N_i$, then for $n > N$, $\sum_{i=1}^\infty |x_i^{(n)}| < \epsilon$.
- Therefore $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^\infty |x_i^{(n)}| = 0$

Edit: I meant $n$ as a superscript, not an exponent $x_i^{(n)}$ is the $n^{th}$ term in the sequence $x_i$

Comment: How do you make sure that $\sup_iN_i$ is finite and not equal to $\infty$?

Answer (score 1):

The question has been answered in a comment but I add a counterexample here: Consider $x_i=\tfrac{1}{\sqrt[n]{in}}$. This satisfies your requirement but $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^\infty|x_i^n|$ diverges regardless of $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Take, for example,
$$
x_i^{(n)}=\biggl(\frac1{2^n}\biggr)^i
$$
for $n\ge 1$ and $i\ge0$. Then we have that $x_i^{(n)}\to0$ as $n\to\infty$. Using the formula for a geometric series for each $n\ge1$,
$$
\sum_{i=0}^\infty\biggl(\frac1{2^n}\biggr)^i=\frac1{1-2^{-n}},
$$
but
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^\infty\biggl(\frac1{2^n}\biggr)^i=1.
$$